# передача информации с удалённого сервера локальному процессу

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

хотелось бы после установления *ssh*-соединения с удалённым сервером иметь возможность передать оттуда, с удалённого сервера, некую информацию запущенному локально процессу. как это осуществить?

**например**: я получаю на удалённом серверер некий *url*, и хотел бы, передав его некой программе/скрипту на удалённом сервере, «открыть» этот *url* в запущенном локально браузере.

понятно, что можно мышкой выделить этот *url* в окне эмулятора терминала, и вставить его в адресную строку браузера. а как это осуществить без мышки и «копи-паста»?

---

**ещё более конкретно**: я использую на удалённом сервере [*rss*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS)-агрегатор-просмотрщик [newsbeuter](http://newsbeuter.org/) (в популярных дистрибутивах *gnu/linux* присутствуют одноимённые пакеты), который запущен в [*gnu/screen*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), к которому я подключаюсь с помощью *ssh* (`ssh -t сервер screen -RD имя-скрина-с-newsbeuter-ом`), и в нём (*newsbeuter-е*) есть возможность, нажав `o`, открыть ссылку на просматриваемый топик в указанном браузере (по умолчанию — *lynx*). но программа-то запущена на удалённом сервере, а я хотел бы открывать ссылку в **локальном** браузере.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно воспользоваться *ssh-туннелем* с помощью опции `-R`. примерно так:

```
$ ssh -R 1234:localhost:5678 ...
```

после запуска *ssh-сессии* (и только в течение её работы) *sshd* на удалённой стороне будет слушать указанный tcp-порт — 1234, и поступившую туда информацию будет ретранслировать локальному процессу, слушающему второй указанный порт — 5678.

передать текст (на удалённом сервере) на порт 1234 можно, например, с помощью программы *netcat*:

```
$ echo текст | nc -q 0 localhost 1234
```

опция `-q 0` — чтобы программа *netcat* сразу же завершала работу после передачи.

принять же текст, поступивший в порт 5678 (уже на локальной машине) можно с помощью той же программы:

```
$ netcat -l -p 5678
```

текст поступит в *stdout* программы, а сама программа, получив сигнал об окончании связи, сразу же завершит работу. понятно, что слушающий процесс должен быть запущен раньше, нежели передающий.

---

**по поводу newsbeuter и локального браузера**:

передачу *url-а* можно задать непосредственно в конфигурационной опции `browser`, добавив в файл `~/.newsbeuter/config` строку примерно такого вида:

```
browser "echo %u | nc -q 0 localhost 1234"
```

а на локальной стороне можно запустить примерно такой бесконечный цикл:

```
$ while true; do xdg-open $(nc -l -p 5678); done
```

*xdg-open* — это программное средство «открытия» файлов/ссылок и прочих [*uri*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI). например:

```
$ xdg-open /путь/к/картинке.png
$ xdg-open http://сайт/страница
```